# Serial communication trouble C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I got some trouble with my console application. I'm trying to retrieve data from a serial connection with a barcode scanner.

The problem is that:
- first read is perfect;
- second read results incorrect unless I wait approximately one minute.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

class PortDataReceived
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM10");

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;

        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        mySerialPort.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();

        mySerialPort.Close();

    }

    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
        Console.WriteLine(indata);                
    }
}
```

and here is the result of 2 reads of the same barcode without waiting enough time from the first to the second read:

```
Press any key to continue...
Data Received:
229000400718
Data Received:
2
Data Received:
2
Data Received:
9
Data Received:
0
Data Received:
0
Data Received:
0
Data Received:
4
Data Received:
0
Data Received:
0
Data Received:
7
Data Received:
1
Data Received:
8
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try port.DtrEnable = true?

Comment: seems like your barcode scanner sends barcode number for first time and then char by char same barcode. Have you tried to use some serial port monitor to view what scanner actually sending?

Comment: I've already tried port.DtrEnable = true and nothing changes.
I've also used HyperTerminal for monitoring and there's no problem: I receive every string correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the data of the second read comes in char by char, so I would use a StringBuilder b and append incoming data until a valid barcode was received and is contained in b (ie check validity against a database)

I suggest something like this:

```
private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

    while(!IsValidBarcode(b.ToString())) 
    {
        b.Append(sp.ReadExisting());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
    Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
}

private static Boolean IsValidBarcode(String s)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return false;

    // (1) Query a database for expected barcodes ...
    // (2) Check s for Start-Stop-Characters ...
    // (3) Query the device for completed barcode ...

    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

or this

```
private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

    Thread.Sleep(1000);     // 1 second delay for testing purposes

    b.Append(sp.ReadExisting());

    Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
    Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
}
```

Comment: The data of the second read come in random quantity. Sometime char by char and sometimes divided into block of 3-4 chars.. 
Barcods don't have always the same length and there's no "new line" character..

Comment: There must be some information to determine the end of a barcode (stop char, length, ...) Otherwise I suggest to refere to the barcode-reader driver's documentation

Comment: Sorry for spamming comments. Maybe the first read is perfect, because it is the first time the static EventHandler is invoked and there is a slight delay before the data is actually read from COM10. Have you checked what happened at the third or fourth scan? Have you tried to insert a slight Delay like Thread.Sleep(100) before actually reading the data by sp.ReadExisting() ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an ending character to know when your message is completed. Most people are using a `\r\n (13,10)` and read from the serial port to the end of the line (i.e. \r\n).

You are getting an event for each character and reading it too quickly.

Comment: Usually the process would be Serial.ReadLine() instead of Serial.ReadExisting(). Then the barcoder needs to be configured to send CRLF (most of them are default configured this way).

Comment: I'm using the Motorola DS457 and it seems there's no CRLF character. I've tried to use serial.ReadLine() but nothing compares in my shell as the method is always waiting..

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of timer to check if the multiple characters being read are part of a single read or if they are 2 different scans.  The time between the event firing for your second scan is probably very short, simply set a timer to start after an event firing, if this expires before the next event then it is the end of the barcode, if not append the read to the previous (use a buffer of some sort).

Answer (score 0):

Luca Pillin, I have just included thread.sleep for 3 seconds and it solves the issue

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO.Ports;

class PortDataReceived
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM2");

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;

        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        mySerialPort.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();

        mySerialPort.Close();

    }

    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
    //   
        string indata = string.Empty;
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        **Thread.Sleep(3000);**
                 indata = sp.ReadExisting();


        Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
        Console.WriteLine(indata);
    }
}
```